# In C++'s Eigen library, how do I solve: invalid use of incomplete type ‘const class Eigen::MatrixSquareRootReturnValue<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >’

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I'm using the Eigen library in C++ to obtain the square root of a float square matrix:

```
  MatrixXf gPrime(QUAD_EKF_NUM_STATES, QUAD_EKF_NUM_STATES);
  gPrime.setIdentity();

  auto sqrtG = gPrime.sqrt();
```

when I compile it I got the following error:

```
.../src/QuadEstimatorEKF.cpp:255:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘const class Eigen::MatrixSquareRootReturnValue<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >’
   auto sqrtG = gPrime.sqrt()
                               ^
In file included from /.../lib/Eigen/Core:346,
                 from /.../lib/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /.../src/QuadEstimatorEKF.h:11,
                 from /.../src/QuadEstimatorEKF.cpp:2:
/.../lib/Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:286:34: note: declaration of ‘class Eigen::MatrixSquareRootReturnValue<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >’
 template<typename Derived> class MatrixSquareRootReturnValue;
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What does 'incomplete type' mean and what should I do to fix it?

I'm using C++ 11 and g++ 8.1.1.

Comment: If you want the matrix square root, follows Darklighter's answer, if you wanted a coefficient-wise square root, then do either `gPrime.cwiseSqrt()` or `gPrime.array().sqrt()` or `sqrt(gPrime.array())`.  (they are all the same, just a matter of taste).

Answer (score 4):

Searching for the [documentation of that function](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__MatrixFunctions__Module.html#matrixbase_sqrt) reveals that it is part of Eigen-unsupported and (at the top)

> To use this module, add
>   `#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>`
>   at the start of your source file.

> invalid use of incomplete type

means that the compiler only finds a declaration but a definition is required at the point of use.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its looking for something more than the P_old.sqrt(), you will need to have a look at what this object looks like, it might have getters/setters or atomic types you might need to use.

Read up about [forward declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) to understand why you got this error, fixing it should be straightforward.

Comment: Sorry the error information was pre-refactoring, already corrected.